# Delete an image file but it seems still exists

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I displayed an image file in an image view. But since I need change picture, then I delete the previous image file. But once build and run, that deleted image still exists in image view.

The image seems not be deleted.

Does anyone know why this kind of situation occur?

Any suggestion, solutions, comments are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share your code ? what you are doing is not that much clear.

Comment: Just clean the code by **Clean All**, reset the simulator and run again. it happens many times

Comment: clean the app from product, and delete the app from the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

clean your build, remove application from the simulator/device, and then reinstall, it will help.